# Missing argument for parameter 'completionHandler' in call

Tags: swift, completionhandler, completion

I used the function geocodeAddressString which worked in swift 1.0, but not in swift2. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code and how i can fix this? Thank you!

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, {(placemarks: [AnyObject], error: NSError) -> Void in  //Error: Missing argument for parameter 'completionHandler' in call

        if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
            annotation.coordinate = location
            annotation.title = "\(StudentArray[student].firstName), \(StudentArray[student].lastName)"
            annotation.subtitle = "\(StudentArray[student].grade)"
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

Either specify the `completionHandler` parameter name:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: { placemarks, error in
    if let placemark = placemarks.first as? CLPlacemark {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "\(StudentArray[student].firstName), \(StudentArray[student].lastName)"
        annotation.subtitle = "\(StudentArray[student].grade)"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
})
```

Or use trailing closure syntax (see *Trailing Closure* section of [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94) chapter of *The Swift Programming Language*), where you pull the closure out from within the `(` and `)` and put it after the `)`:

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { placemarks, error in
    if let placemark = placemarks.first as? CLPlacemark {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "\(StudentArray[student].firstName), \(StudentArray[student].lastName)"
        annotation.subtitle = "\(StudentArray[student].grade)"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this example! The trailing closure syntax always confused me since it omitted a part of the parameter, but now I see it is just short hand practice.

Answer (score 1):

Add in the argument before the completion handler.

```
geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject], error: NSError) -> Void in  // Added argument for parameter 'completionHandler' in call

    if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(placemark.location.coordinate.latitude, placemark.location.coordinate.longitude)
        annotation.coordinate = location
        annotation.title = "\(StudentArray[student].firstName), \(StudentArray[student].lastName)"
        annotation.subtitle = "\(StudentArray[student].grade)"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }

})
```